# activerecord not like query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I could not find an activerecord equivalent of "Not Like". I was able to find a `where.not`, but that will check if a string does not match a value, as so:

```
User.where.not(name: 'Gabe')

is the same as:

User.where('name != ?', 'Gabe')
```

I was looking for a NOT LIKE, where the value is not contained in the string. The equivalent sql query would look like as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name NOT LIKE '%Gabe%'
```

In ActiveRecord I can currently get away with the following:

```
User.where("name NOT LIKE ?", "%Gabe%")
```

But that leaves a lot to be desired. Any new additions to Rails 4 to facilitate this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have pointed out ActiveRecord does not have a nice syntax for building `like` statements. I would suggest using Arel as it makes the query less database platform specific (will use `ilike` for sqlite & `like` for other platforms).

```
User.where(User.arel_table[:name].does_not_match('%Gabe%'))
```

You could also implement this as a scope to contain the implementation to the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_matching, 
    -> (str) { where(arel_table[:name].does_not_match("%#{str}%")) }
end
```

Comment: I followed up and found `does_not_match` here, in case others are wondering: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Predications

Answer (score 20):

Well, you can do something like:

```
User.where.not("name LIKE ?", "%Gabe%")
```

Note: This is only available in Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ActiveRecord does not have a `like` query builder. I agree that the raw 'NOT LIKE' leaves a lot to be desired; you could make it a scope (`scope :not_like, (column, val) -> { ... }`), but AR itself does not do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just addition to the answer of "where.not" of active record. "where.not" will exclude null values also. i.e. Query User.where.not(name: 'Gabe') will leave record with name 'Gabe' but it also exclude name column with NULL values. So in this scenario the solution would be

User.where.not(name: 'Gabe')
    .or(User.where(name: nil))

Comment: extremely important point about a (to me) completely non-intuitive "feature" of activerecord